# Axios Interceptor (Response) doesn't update the header

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios

In my react application, I am trying to implement silent refresh for the access token I use for my requests. Everything related to the Axios request interceptor setting Authorization header is working fine. However, when I get a 401 response from the backend I retry the original request after making a refresh token request and setting the new header. I get the below error

```
    react_devtools_backend.js:4012 DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'function(header, parser) {
    header = normalizeHeader(header);
    if (!header)
      return void 0;
    const key = findKey(this, header);
    if (key) {
      const value = this[key];
      if (!parser) {
        return value;
      }
      if (parser === true) {
        return parseTokens(value);
      }
      if (utils_default.isFunction(parser)) {
        return parser.call(this, value, key);
      }
      if (utils_default.isRegExp(parser)) {
        return parser.exec(value);
      }
      throw new TypeError("parser must be boolean|regexp|function");
    }
  }' is not a valid HTTP header field value.
    at setRequestHeader (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=18256307:1209:17)
    at Object.forEach (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=18256307:89:10)
    at dispatchXhrRequest (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=18256307:1208:21)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at xhrAdapter (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=18256307:1112:10)
    at Axios.dispatchRequest (http://localhost:5173/node_modules/.vite/deps/axios.js?v=18256307:1425:10)
    at async NotFound404.useQuery.retry [as queryFn] (http://localhost:5173/src/pages/404.tsx?t=1669973204409:60:12)
```

Here is the Axios client

```
import axios from "axios";

export const APIClient = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5050/api",
    withCredentials: false,
});
```

Here you can find the react custom hook I used, it has both the request and the response Axios interceptors

```
import { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from "axios";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { APIClient } from "../api";
import { requestRefresh, selectToken, useAppDispatch } from "../store";

export const useAPIClient = () => {
    // react router related
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    // react redux store related
    const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
    const token = useSelector(selectToken);

    const APIRequestIntercept = APIClient.interceptors.request.use(
        (config: AxiosRequestConfig) => {
            // Do something before request is sent
            if (
                config?.headers !== undefined &&
                (token !== "" || token !== null)
            ) {
                if (config.headers !== undefined) {
                    config.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${token}`;
                }
            }

            return config;
        },
        (error) => {
            // Do something with request error
            return Promise.reject(error);
        }
    );

    const APIResponseIntercept = APIClient.interceptors.response.use(
        (response: AxiosResponse<any, any>) => {
            // Any status codes that fails outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
            // Do something with response error
            return response;
        },
        async (error) => {
            // Any status codes that falls outside the range of 2xx cause this function to trigger
            // Do something with response error
            if (error?.response && (token !== "" || token !== null)) {
                const prevRequest = error?.config;

                if (error?.response.status === 401 && !prevRequest?._retry) {
                    // refresh the access token and set the auth store state
                    // dispatch refresh async action and it will set the new token
                    const response: any = await dispatch(
                        requestRefresh()
                    ).unwrap();

                    // start to resend the previous failed request
                    prevRequest._retry = true;

                    // set the prevRequest headers
                    prevRequest.headers[
                        "Authorization"
                    ] = `Bearer ${response.data.accessToken}`;

                    // return the previous request
                    return APIClient(prevRequest);
                } else if (error?.response.status === 403) {
                    // navigate the user to sign in page
                    navigate("/sign_in", { replace: true });
                    return;
                } else {
                    return Promise.reject(error);
                }
            } else {
                return Promise.reject(error);
            }
        }
    );

    return APIClient;
};
```

I made I simple request using the `APIClient` instance with React Query in a component

```
import { useAPIClient } from "../hooks";

export function SimpleComponent() {
    // API request related
    const apiClient = useAPIClient();

    useQuery(
        ["dummy"],
        async () => {
            return await apiClient.get("/auth/dummy_json");
        },
        {
            retry: false,
            onSuccess: (response) => {
               console.log("res: ", response);
            },
            onError: (error) => {
               console.log("error: ", error);
            },
        }
    );

    return (<div>Simple Component</div>);
}
```